# Install wordpress package always require apache?

Tags: debian, software-installation, package-management, wordpress, lighttpd

Debian's WordPress package depends on `apache|httpd`, lighttpd also provides httpd, but when I try to install WordPress, apt requires me to install apache2!

What I should do? I want to use only lighttpd !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Debian package page for [wordpress](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/wordpress), it appears that lighttpd should satisfy the dependency. However, it also requires `libapache2-mod-php5` *or* `php5`, which is why I think it still pulls in Apache: while you have installed lighttpd, you may have forgotten to install the matching PHP package.

Make sure `lighttpd` and `php5` are both installed before installing `wordpress`, and that should fix your problem.

Comment: Well, may be it's right, the key is `php5-cgi`